# MS SQL SERVER 2005 + SQLAlchemy + Stored Procedure + output parameter

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

From my python code, I am trying to execute stored procedure. Stored Procedure return integer value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC
  @empID char(10),
  @oldEmpList XML,
  @newEmpList XML,
  @Status INT OUTPUT
AS 
  -- sp body
  SET @Status = 1
RETURN 
GO
```

python

```
t = text('EXEC MY_PROC :empID, :oldEmpList, :newEmpList, :Status',
         bindparams=[bindparam('empID', type_=String, value='1234'),
                     bindparam('oldEmpList', type_=TEXT, value='<emp><id>1</id><id>2</id>'),
                     bindparam('newEmpList', type_=TEXT, value='<emp><id>e01</id><id>e02</id>'),
                     bindparam('Status', type_=Integer, value=0, isoutparam=True)])
result = CMS_DBSession.execute(t)
print result.out_parameters
```

it print nothing as output parameter.

How can I access output paramter

Answer (score 0):

There is a working solution here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/dn-W0rrlwxk

That would give something like :

```
t = text('SET NOCOUNT ON; declare @Status int; EXEC MY_PROC :empID, :oldEmpList, :newEmpList, @Status; Select @Status; SET NOCOUNT OFF;',
     bindparams=[bindparam('empID', type_=String, value='1234'),
                 bindparam('oldEmpList', type_=TEXT, value='<emp><id>1</id><id>2</id>'),
                 bindparam('newEmpList', type_=TEXT, value='<emp><id>e01</id><id>e02</id>'))
result = CMS_DBSession.execute(t)
# then get the select result
```